# Understanding Fraleigh's derivation of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

Here's how Fraleigh (informally) derives Fermat's Little Theorem in his classic Abstract Algebra text:

> For $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the elements $$1, 2, \dots, p-1$$ form a group of order $p-1$ under multiplication modulo $p$. Since the $\color{blue}{\textrm{order of any element in a group divides the order of the group,}}$ we see that for $b \neq 0 \textrm{ and } b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, we have $\color{red}{b^{p-1} = 1 \textrm{ in } \mathbb{Z}_p}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is isomorphic to the ring of cosets of the form $a + p\mathbb{Z}$, we have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\mod p)$.

Can someone please explain how the statement in red came about? Also, is the statement in blue coming from the Theorem of Lagrange?

Comment: What is the order of the multiplicative group of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: @quasi It's $p-1$, isn't it?

Comment: Right, so do you know the theorem that the order of an element of a finite group divides the order of the group?

Comment: @quasi That sounds like the Theorem of Lagrange to me, but my issue is that the Theorem of Lagrange is not about the order of elements (its about the order of subgroups)

Comment: For a finite group, the order of an element is the same as the order of the cyclic subgroup generated by that element. Now apply Lagrange.

Comment: So if $b\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $b\ne 0$ has order $s$ say, then we have $st=p-1$ for some positive integer $t$, hence $b^{p-1}=b^{st}=(b^s)^t=1^t=1$.

Comment: If $b$ (defined the way it is) has order $s$, then how come $st = p -1$? Is is due to the division algorithm (that is, due to the fact that $s$ divides $p-1$)?

Comment: For integers $a,b$ we say $a$ divides $b$ (notation $a{\,\mid\,}b$) if $b=ax$ for some integer $x$. Thus "$s$ divides $p-1$" _means_ $p-1=st$ for some integer $t$ (and since $s$ and $p-1$ are both positive, so is $t$).